# Failed to use gradle--retrolambda build project in OSX

Tags: android, macos, gradle, rx-java, retrolambda

I'm a rookie with OSX. Today I try to use RxJava and Retrolambda in Android Studio, Retrolambda needs gradle--retrolambda.

So I started config:

1.I pasted a little code to ~/.bash_profile to set the JAVA7_HOME and JAVA8_HOME

```
export JAVA7_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home   
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH 
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

export JAVA8_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH 
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

It seems work fine , I check it use terminal

```
echo $JAVA8_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
echo $JAVA7_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then I following Others article

2.Edited Android Studio -> Preference -> Path Variables
Added "JAVA8_HOME" and "JAVA7_HOME" ,same as above

3.Edited build.gradle (Project)

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

4.Edited build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'  #Added here!


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ezioshiki.demoproject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    #Added here!
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

#Added here!
String java8 = getJavaVersion(8)
String java7 = getJavaVersion(7)
retrolambda {
    jdk java8 //have tried with JAVA8_HOME
    oldJdk java7 //have tried with JAVA6_HOME
    javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 //have matched the above with VERSION_1_6
}

String getJavaVersion(Integer v) {
    def sout = new StringBuffer()
    def proc = "/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.$v".execute()
    proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, new StringBuffer())
    proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
    return sout.toString().replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    compile 'net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:2.0.6'
    compile 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.2'
}
```

I followed https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda/issues/61 , because gradle-retrolambda official suggestion cannot find Java8, and this issues worked.

But it gave me :

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileRetrolambdaDebug
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
```

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes

at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)

at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
... 12 more
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.


com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.143 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I can't handle this. Anyone could help me ? Very very thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all .java files to the root package. That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have configured my OSx environment,

1. install latest java 8
2. edit your .bash_profile (located in your home directory) and add this lines:

   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
   export JAVA7_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`

*now "java -version" command must shows java 1.8, but retrolambda can also access to java 7 home directory.

3. add these lines to your project build.gradle file:

   dependencies {
       ...
       classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
       classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
4. apply retrolambda plugin to your android app module build.gradle:

   apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

*there is no need to add compile dependencies to this module.